# How to make a composable screen scale to different phones (screen) sizes in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, scale

I am trying to create a composable that can work for each screen by scaling its content to the appropriate size depending on the type of phone screen used. Note: Not dependent on other types of devices (ex. ipads, computer screens etc.) How can I achieve this in jetpack compose? Appreciate the help!

Emulator screen (Pixel 4a API 33): https://gyazo.com/5343ea42d8cbaf3d62b9ac57480157e6

Phone Screen (Samsung S9): https://gyazo.com/0aee7c6a9757d78ed540df0b855ce1ff

Emulator Screen (Pixel 3 API 34): https://gyazo.com/21875fdb01e1a1b6709efbf28e4ca91d

As seen there is a slight difference in the button's size. Now there might be more differences across other variants of phones.

Is there a way to make it scale more consistently across other devices?

Comment: You can use WindowSizeClass to achieve it. Based on size of display you can show different composables or applying specific Modifiers.
Article to read: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! Will check it out @Injent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see that much of difference in your provided UIs but here is a good rule of thumb to follow:

> Sometimes, we have composable that just have a fixed size. But very
> often we also don’t. In these cases,  avoid using hardcoded DP values
> for a composable’s dimensions and switch to relative sizes using
> modifiers such as fillMaxSize(), weight() or widthIn().

So like instead of having a `Button` of `300.dp` because it looks cool/right/great on your test phone, it may not look good or even half rendered on other phones because they have small screens (old phones) or big screens (newer phones).

Instead of having :

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen() {
   //some code e.g(email and password TextFields)
   Button(
         onClick={ //do Something },
         modifier = Modifier.width(300.dp)
   ) {
      Text(....)
   }
}
```

you want to have this:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen() {
   //some code e.g(email and password TextFields)
   Button(
         onClick= { //do Something },
         modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
   ) {
      Text(....)
   }
}
```

and now you could play with the value of `fillMaxWidth` as you want and the UI will have the same scale on all screen.

**Note**: this is applicable when talking about different sizes of phones if you want to consider your UI to support different devices (tablets, foldables, desktop...) I highly recommend checking [the documentation for Adaptive Layouts](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! I have been trying to play around with fillMaxWidth and setting it to lets say: FillMaxWidth(0.8f). Is this the correct way of scaling composables for different types of phone screens? @Ayman Ait

Comment: @JosefM yeah that is the right way either using fillmaxheight/width or using weight modifier

Comment: Alright, I understand, then I am on the right track! Appreciate the help and feedback! @Ayman Ait